# Why can't I search for a wildcard in combination with a tag?

Tags: google-ngram-viewer

Google Ngram Viewer lets you use [wildcards in combination with tags](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info#), e.g. [`the *_ADJ book`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+%2A_ADJ+book&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) searches for the most common adjectives between 'the' and 'book':

[image]

However, a similar search for [`the book is *_ADJ`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+book+is+%2A_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) does not work; it says 'No valid ngrams to plot!'.

[image]

Why does this not work? Do I need to use an alternative syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a reference to back this up, but after some experiments it looks like you can't use a wildcard/tag combination in a query of four or more terms. So, as an alternative, I could search for [`book is *_ADJ`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=book+is+%2A_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3):

[image]

Comment: I don't use this app but I think that include "the" "this" and other similar words might be part of the problem.